# python 3 : comparing nested dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, compare

I found multiple answers on how to compare complex Python objects and ended up finding the [deep_eq](https://gist.github.com/samuraisam/901117) module and this answer several times, also found in its comments : why not use `==` like this:

```
a = {
  "a": 2, "b": 1,
  "e": {
    "C": 2, "F": 1
  },
  "f": 4, "z": 3
}

b = {
  "a": 2, "b": 1,
  "e": {
    "C": 2, "F": 1
  },
  "f": 4, "z": 3
}

c = {
  "a": 2, "b": 1,
  "e": {
    "C": 2, "F": 2  # F differs here
  },
  "f": 4, "z": 3
}

assert a == b
assert a != c
```

Could someone explain to me what is the proper method to compare complex, nested dictionaries?

I don't need a function but more a why, and is there an instance of when `==` isn't sufficient?

Comment: The best way is indeed to use `d1 == d2`. You need to focus on a specific problem; right now it appears there isn't any.

Comment: what do you mean but "focus on a specific problem" ?

Comment: You say you want to compare two dictionaries and that this can be done via `==`. Then what is your question? Do you have a specific use case where `==` doesn't work? Apart from performance, I cannot imagine.

Comment: that's exactly my point : I see everywhere complex functions to do that job, even here on Stackoverflow and I then wonder : why ? and are there any cases when it doesn't work ?

Comment: The one you linked (`deep_eq`) apparently also compares iterators and generators by exhausting them; Python won't do that by default. Another reason I could imagine is performance for very specific data structures, where it is preferable to compare a specific path through the structure because it is expected to fail often (based on heuristics). But this is all very vague with a concrete example.